# How can I make the SSID for my guest network hidden on my Synology Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssid

I own a Synology RT2600ac router which broadcasts a network on both 2.4/5 GHz with a hidden SSID. The configuration for this network looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of router configuration settings]

The dropdown circled in the red box is set to "Hide", which is how I tell the router that it shouldn't broadcast the SSID.

I'd like to broadcast a guest network, which is functionality that the router has, but it doesn't seem that there's a dropdown to make the network hidden. I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to hide the SSID of the guest network, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is this possible?

I'm running SRM version `SRM 1.2.3-8017 Update 4`

Answer (score 4):

The UI doesn't provide a way to do this, but it is possible. The following answer describes a workaround that I've tested on version `SRM 1.2.3-8017 Update 4` of the SRM.

The workaround requires enabling SSH access to the router. To do this, browse to the **Control Panel** application and then the **Services** tab. Check the box ticked *Enable SSH Service*.

[image: Screenshot of the Control Panel application, with the services tab selected]

Once you've done this, you can connect to your router via SSH. Log in with the `root` account, using the password you have set on your primary administrator account (the username `admin`.) Even if you've disabled this account, this is still the password you use to log into the `root` account via SSH.

Once you've authenticated, change directories to `/usr/syno/etc/wifi`. If you `ls` here, you'll see a number of files that are used to configure the wireless networks broadcast by the router.

[image: The output of the <code>ls</code> command is shown here.]

A number of files are listed that match the pattern `wifi_ap_{mac_address}`. These files configure the different broadcast settings. In each of these files is a configuration line: `guest_display_ssid=yes`. If you edit each of these files to have the line say `guest_display_ssid=no`, and then reboot the router (you can use `shutdown -r now`), guest networks (presently, and any enabled through the UI in the future) will not broadcast their SSID.

It isn't clear whether these settings persist after an SRM update, but I would guess that they do. This is in the configuration for a user's network, so it should remain untouched on updates.